# Why are my products not showing in magento?

Tags: magento

I came to check on my magento site this morning and as far as I know it was working as it should but when I went on a product to show me more detail it loads the page but nothing shows up, my browser says the page has fully loaded but nothing shows up at all its completely blank, as far as I know it was working 2 days ago and nothing has been altered, I've cleared the cache, reindexed the data and still nothing and when it does manage to load something it looks like this:

[image]

Im having to download a full backup from my hosting account to see if I can restore it back to normal, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: More info would also be appreciated. We don't know literally anything about your website.

Comment: Check the indexes/caches and see if any of them are out of date and/or in progress.

Comment: What more info do you require ?, and I've reindexed the data and cleared the cache everything is green good to go

Comment: Access logs. Error logs. Exception logs. Error reports.

Comment: Recent configuration changes you have applied that might have triggered this behavior but who's effects might have been delayed/hidden by the cache.

Comment: Recent code changes (including recently installed pluggins) that might have created the problem.

Comment: Check if cPanel available disk space is full -- trying to create a file or add to a log may trigger an error because of a full disk which then stops the PHP process from generating your entire page.

Comment: (Ab)use your imagination -- your original question literally had no relevant info in it. It's like saying "hey my android phone doesn't work, do you know why?".

Comment: We have unlimited space and bandwidth, error logs where turned off on magento site, I've undone any changes I made in the css, nothing worked now on the phone to technical support

Comment: CSS wouldn't have created a problem like this.

Comment: add to .htaccess `php_flag display_startup_errors on` `php_flag display_errors on` `php_flag html_errors on` and reload page. Also you can enable logging in backend